# URL rewrite from trailing string to GET variable

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-8

I've searched for this, but can't seem to come up with the right search terms to find - seems it would be a common question.

WIMP, IIS version is 8

I want to come up with a rewrite rule:
Incoming URL:  http://example.com/1a2b3cdef
Rewritten to: http://example.com?p=1a2b3cdef

Note, the start of this url will always be "http://example.com/" (not the real domain name), that will never change.

From there my default document of index.php will retrieve the GET variable p.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is the configuration that can be applied in web.config.

```
<defaultDocument>

            <files>

                <add value="index.php" />

            </files>

        </defaultDocument>

        <rewrite>

            <rules>

                <rule name="rewrite" enabled="true">

                    <match url="^[_0-9a-z]+" />

                    <action type="Rewrite" url="?p={R:0}" />

                </rule>

            </rules>

        </rewrite>
```

Comment: Thank you Jokies.  I appreciated your time here.  Seems so simple, but what I was trying wasn't working for me in IIS.  Yours works perfectly!

Comment: @John. I'm so glad that the rule could fix your problem. It is so appreciated if you could accept it as answer so the rule may help other people.